# Having multiple elements in complexType

Tags: xml, xsd

So I want to write an XML Schema for my XML file. The problem I am having now is that I have an element and I want multiple elements in it, but not declaring that amount. So that I will be able to add or remove elements with a program to keep the file dynamic.

I am fairly new to xml and xml schema so I dont now where to start.
This is what I got so far - it only allows me to have on dish at a time, but as said, I want multiple ones of no particular amount.

```
Schema:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="menu">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="starter">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="dish" type="dish"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
...
</xsd:schema>

XML:
<menu>
<starter>
    <dish>
        <name> 
            Salad
        </name>
        <price>
            4.00
        </price>
    </dish>
    <dish>
        <name>
            Bread
        </name>
        <price>
            2.50
        </price>
    </dish>
</starter>
```

My goal at the end is to be able to add and remove as many dish tags, as I want. But with this the validator says, that there is no child expected after the first one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the anwser!

If you're using the choice tag and setting the maxOccurs attribute to unbounded, then its possible to have unlimited tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:element name="menu">
<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="starter">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="dish" type="dish"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
...
</xsd:schema>
```